# Find the values of $a,b$ so that the given limit equals $2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{(a\sin^2x)(b\log\cos x)\over x^4}={1\over 2}$$

My initial thought was to apply L'Hopital Rule so that at some stage a condition appears where i will have to set some value for $a,b$ to get the limit. This  doesn't work though as the numerator keeps expanding. Need some hint on this

Comment: Just pull out $ab$.  The values of $a$ and $b$ are not determined, only $ab$.

Comment: The choice of $a,b$ is not unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$$

and

$$\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{x^2}=\frac{\ln(\cos^2x)}{2x^2}=\frac{\ln(1-\sin^2x)}{-\sin^2x}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2\left(-\frac12\right)$$

We know $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}h=1$$

Comment: okie, i didnt think about splitting it. Thanks !!

Comment: @AmanMittal, my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use 
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log\cos x}{x^2} = -1/2
$$

Comment: the last limit should be $-\frac12$